# Como abrir, via intent, a app Google Maps em determinada Latitude/Longitude?

Tags: android, google-maps

Usando esta regra eu consigo visualizar as informações do banco de dados. Estou querendo colocar um botão para pegar a latitude e longitude do banco de dados para quando clicar nele abrir o google maps.

```
public class UsuarioAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Usuario> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Usuario> lista;

    public UsuarioAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Usuario> lista){
        super(context,0,lista);
        this.context = context;
        this.lista = lista;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Usuario itemPosicao = this.lista.get(position);

        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(this.context).inflate(R.layout.item_lista,null);
        final View layout = convertView;

        TextView textViewNome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNome);
        textViewNome.setText(itemPosicao.getNome());

        TextView textViewCrm = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCrm);
        textViewCrm.setText(itemPosicao.getCrm());

        TextView textViewTelefone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTelefone);
        textViewTelefone.setText(itemPosicao.getTelefone());

        TextView textViewConvenios = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewConvenios);
        textViewConvenios.setText(itemPosicao.getConvenios());


    TextView textViewLatitude = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewLatitude);
    textViewLatitude.setText(itemPosicao.getLatitude());

    TextView textViewLongitude = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewLongitude);
    textViewLongitude.setText(itemPosicao.getLongitude());

        Button button = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonComoChegar);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Como eu posso fazer isto?

Comment: Qual é a sua dificuldade? Ir buscar esses dados ao BD, abrir o Google Maps ou ambas?

Comment: ambas, queria abrir o botão buscando os dados de latitude e longitude que estão na tabela do bando (tabela = longitute) e (tabela = latutide) e abrindo o (app) do google maps.

Comment: De onde você está a buscar os dados referentes a "Nome", "Crm", "Telefone", etc?

Comment: do meu banco local postgresql

Comment: Então porque não inclui também a latitude e longitude no array que passa ao adapter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tendo a latitude e longitude disponíveis na classe *Usuario* esses dados poderão ser obtidos da mesma forma que "Nome", "Crm", "Telefone", etc.
Depois é só criar o *Intent* para lançar o *Google maps*.

```
    .......
    .......
    double final latitude = itemPosicao.getLatitude();
    double final longitude = itemPosicao.getLongitude();

    Button button = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonComoChegar);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String strUri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:" + 
                             latitude + "," + longitude;
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                                       Uri.parse(strUri));

            intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps",
                                "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");

            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

É possível também usar um intent construído assim:

```
Uri mapAppUri = Uri.parse("geo:" + latitude + ","
        + longitude + "?q="
        + latitude + ","
        + longitude
        + "(" + Uri.encode("nome do local") + ")");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, mapAppUri);
```

A vantagem é que se houver outras aplicações instaladas que possam lidar com localizações elas serão apresentadas ao utilizador para ele escolher uma.

Comment: Obrigado pelo ajuda ramaral, deu tudo certo aqui.